# VECM model output - where is the long run relationship?

Tags: econometrics, least-squares, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

1. So I'm getting the following EViews output, but where on earth is the long run relationship? Do I have to estimate it separately using OLS?
2. If you have to estimate it yourself via OLS, I've already done that, but the regression gives me a very high intercept, so the second time series does not drive the first one much. This causes my model to be inaccurate at forecasting in an environment where there is a strong bear or bull market (as has been the case with rates recently) because my long run relationship remains artificially high due to the high intercept. Would it be completely inaccurate for me to model a long-term relationship of my own (e.g., a dynamic moving average of some sort)?

Thank you!

EDIT: I think it's the  Cointegrating Eq I'm looking for, but still, why does it give virtually no slope for the 1Y coefficient (-0.006946)? It doesn't tie with the OLS I run, which gives something closer to 10Y = 75 + 0.3 1Y, whereas this model seems to imply the long run relationship is 10Y = 108 + 0.0 1Y.

EDIT2: I found that you can remove the intercept by going to Quick > Estimate VAR > Cointegration tab. This makes my model far better from a forecasting standpoint, but I question whether or not it remains mathematically valid (I was taught you shouldn't run a regression without an intercept). And I still don't get why my OLS differs from the long run model EViews gives me.

```
Vector Error Correction Estimates       
Date: 04/27/15   Time: 18:31        
Sample (adjusted): 6/06/2013 5/30/2014      
Included observations: 250 after adjustments        
Standard errors in ( ) & t-statistics in [ ]        

Cointegrating Eq:   CointEq1    

10Y(-1)  1.000000   

1Y(-1)  -0.006946   
        (0.18203)   
        [-0.03816]  

C       -107.9739   

Error Correction:   D(10Y)  D(1Y)

  CointEq1      -0.076370   -0.066728
                (0.02395)    (0.02645)
                [-3.18881]  [-2.52320]

  D(10Y(-1))    -0.124553   -0.044210
                (0.07813)    (0.08628)
                [-1.59415]  [-0.51243]

  D(10Y(-2))    -0.004510    0.012273
                (0.07649)    (0.08447)
                 [-0.05896] [ 0.14530]

  D(1Y(-1))  0.230168    0.047305
                (0.07075)    (0.07812)
               [ 3.25330]   [ 0.60552]

  D(1Y(-2))  0.010678   -0.025593
                (0.07219)    (0.07971)
               [ 0.14792]   [-0.32108]

  C              0.016430    0.038955
                (0.06426)    (0.07096)
               [ 0.25568]   [ 0.54900]

R-squared    0.083589    0.030820
Adj. R-squared   0.064810    0.010960
Sum sq. resids   251.1315    306.2146
S.E. equation    1.014509    1.120258
F-statistic  4.451206    1.551850
Log likelihood  -355.2991   -380.0878
Akaike AIC   2.890393    3.088702
Schwarz SC   2.974908    3.173218
Mean dependent   0.022800    0.038960
S.D. dependent   1.049073    1.126448

Determinant resid covariance (dof adj.)      0.864469
Determinant resid covariance         0.823472
Log likelihood      -685.1911
Akaike information criterion         5.593528
Schwarz criterion        5.790730
```

Comment: The error correction terms are denoted CointEq1. In EViews: press F1, type "vec", hit enter.

Comment: I'm still really confused. I get that CointEq is the coefficient in front of the long run relationship component, but where do you get the long run relationship itself? Do you run the regression yourself? 

Edit: or is the long run relationship 10Y = 107.9739 + 0.006946 1Y based on what I have above? If so, it doesn't tie in with the OLS I run, which gave me roughly 10Y = 75 + 0.3 1Y...

Comment: I would rather work with one model that I believe is the best representation of reality. If that happens to be the VECM, then stick with it. Because if you use VECM for answering one question and then use levels-on-levels regression (`lm(Y10~Y1)`) or differences-on-differences regression (`lm(diff(Y10)~diff(Y1))`) to answer another question, how can you justify that? The different models would give different conclusions for a given question. How would you reconcile these differences to justify using one model over the other to answer one question but not another question?

Comment: On the other hand, if the the long-run relationship as modelled by a VECM is very different from the long-run relationship as modelled by a levels-on-levels regression, that could be a sign of trouble with at least one of the models. The long-run relationship should be estimated superconsistently in a levels-on-levels regression, and it should be estimated (super?)consistently as the first stage of fitting a VECM. The two should roughly coincide. If you find large differences, then perhaps there is something more going on. Structural break? Large conditional heteroskedasticity? Something else?